# How do people have the ability to do super jumps in modern warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I was playing MW2 and was about to shoot an opponent...and then all of a sudden they jumped like 4 stories! How do they do that?

Comment: Superman......?

Comment: Probably a mod of some kind. What platform were you playing on?

Answer (score 2):

I was googling your question and found that it's just a mod on PC or that person is just cheating. And if you couldn't do it during the game I'm going to assume they were cheating.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a cheat. Flag them to a server admin.

In general, while people might be much better than you on reflexes or aiming, if they are significantly better than all rest of the players, or do odd things like fly, jump too high, consistently shoot accurately through walls etc just flag them.

Comment: I would say just being 'significantly better' is not in and of itself a reason to flag. I am not a great player (my career KD is 1.08) but sometimes I'll just dominate and do twice as good as anyone else in the game. One time I went 27/1! Unless they are consistently carrying 10+ KDs or never dying, I wouldn't flag them just for being good.

Comment: @SSumner - updated to make it more obvious:-) thanks

Comment: I consistently post a ratio of 10+ but I don't cheat? Just very difficult to find